# Vuforia video playback video detection issue

Tags: ios, vuforia, audiovideoplayback

I am trying to detect 30 targets and play different video for each target. The problem I am facing is after some 20 images, somehow the videos dont play(I get a cross sign).

Also is there some way to load a video that is required to play and unload others, so that the videos dont hang after some time.

Any help or pointers in right direction highly appretiated.

Comment: did you found any solution and did you using it on ios version?